# Increment counter inside Foreach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I want to output each line in a text document into its own document where the output documents are named 1.txt, 2.txt, etc.
This is my initial code that reads the text documents and outputs the lines one by one.

```
get-content "artists.txt" | Foreach-Object {$_ | set-content "artists\$counter.txt"}
```

But as you can imagine, this outputs always to the same document.

I have tried

```
get-content "artists.txt" | 
  Foreach-Object {$_ | set-content "artists\$counter.txt" } {$counter++}
```

as I have seen suggested online and while this increases the counter, it doesn't do what I want (since it still outputs to the same file).

Not really sure where to insert the counter++ here as inside the Foreach-Object loop itself gives me an error (unless I'm inserting it wrong).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you can use the `ReadCount` property returned by the `Get-Content` cmdlet:

```
get-content "artists.txt" | Foreach-Object {$_ | set-content "artists\$($_.ReadCount).txt" }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53487338/45375) provides an effective solution based on the - obscurely named - `ReadCount` property that `Get-Content` adds to each input line, which reflects the `1`-based *line number*.

Using a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) enables a solution that is both shorter and noticeably faster:

```
Get-Content artists.txt | Set-Content -LiteralPath { "artists\$($_.ReadCount).txt" }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Variable `$counter` must be incremented in the `ForEach-Object` command's `-Process` block, i.e., the block that is executed for each input object (and is typically the *only* block specified, *positionally*).

The 2nd script block you passed, `{$counter++}`, binds to the `-End` parameter, meaning the block to be executed *once*, *after* all pipeline objects have been received.

Therefore, you could have used the following:

```
$counter = 0
Get-Content artists.txt | Foreach-Object { 
  $_ | Set-Content "artists\$((++$counter)).txt"
}
```

The increment operation is embedded in the expandable string for brevity, but you could make it a separate statement.

Note the use of an extra pair  of `(...)` around expression `++$counter`, so as to ensure that the expression's value is also *output*; by default, `++` just increments a variable's value, but doesn't produce output.
The outer `$(...)` - the subexpression operator - is needed in order to embed expressions or commands in expandable strings (`"..."`).

Answer (score 2):

In one-liners, the For-Each object has three positional blocks: `begin`, `process` and `end`:

```
...<piped objects>... | For-Each {...begin...} {...process...} {...end...}
```

An easy and general way to set up a counter is:

```
...<piped objects>... | For-Each {$counter = 0} {...process...} {...end...}
```

because if you need to reuse the one-liner, the `$counter` variable will not be reset.  You can also add code to the `begin` block to start the counter at something else as well.

For your particular case, we just have to initialize `$counter` in a `begin` block and use [mklement0's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) answer:

```
get-content "artists.txt" | Foreach-Object {$counter = 0} {$_ | set-content "artists\$((++$counter.txt))"}
```

You could even use the `end` block to output a summary:

```
For-Each {...} {...} {Write-Host "There were $counter lines read and $counter files created"}
```